# Pygame not exiting on keypress

Tags: python, pygame

I've been following along with a bouncing ball example just to get my chops warmed up with pygame: every time I test my code I have to kill the game window by causing it to freeze, though in my code (taken directly from the pygame website) I state that the game should exit if the Escape key is pressed or the X button on the screen. I get an error

```
    running == False
NameError: name 'running' is not defined
```

my code is

```
   while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running == False
        if event.type ==pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            running == False
```

can I define "running?" such that the game doesn't simply freeze when I try to quit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you should define running to True (`running = True`) above your while loop.  Secondly, you should be checking that value somewhere; easiest is to change `while 1` to `while running`  Third, == is checking for equality, = is setting a value.  You want to check event.type to be pygame.QUIT or KEYDOWN, so those == are correct, but then you want to set running to False, which is `running = False`.  Doing running == False as a statement is not effective.